# Простой слайдер на CSS

Tags: css, css-animation

Быстрый вопрос, - есть страница, на которой картинки должны меняться по таймеру, за счет наслоения на предыдущую. Вот мой код, но там есть только первая анимация.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide2 {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s, 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide3 {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide3 {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_1" />
  <img id="slide2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_2" />
  <img id="slide3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_3" />
</div>
```

Comment: А картинок будет ровно три или разное кол-во?) Кажется нет способа как-то по умному сделать всю анимацию через counter / calc... и придется задротить код для каждого элемента) P.s. на странице не должно быть больше одного id. Это уникальное "имя" элемента.

Comment: Картинок будет всего три

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Правильная ротация получается благодаря z-index. А всё остальное по времени привязывается к одной переменной `--time`. И оказалось, не так и сложно сделать и для большего количества картинок)

```css
:root {
  --time: 3s; /* Время одного пролистывания */
  --qty: 4; /* Количество картинок */
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #000;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  animation: slide calc(var(--time) * var(--qty)) linear infinite;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* кусок задротства - придется редактировать для каждого кол-ва картинок */
.slide:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: var(--time) }
.slide:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) * 2) }
.slide:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) * 3) }

@keyframes slide {
  0% { z-index: 10; }
  5% { left: 0; }
  66% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/cc0000/fff?text=bubu" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/f36700/fff?text=kuku" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/045acf/fff?text=dudu" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/004400/fff?text=moo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно

Comment: мне понравилось текста +1 за креативные тексты :)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов  `bubu` это визитная карточка автобота  Если увидишь на просторах интернета безымянный скрипт, с классом `.bubu`, то однозначно автор его, - [автобот трансформер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC) :)))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а я не обращал внимание на имена классах в его ответах .Теперь запомню )